# Every two elements mean between these two element

Tags: matlab, vector

I am a newbie for Matlab. I try to take every two consecutive elements' means and put it between these two consecutive elements. For example;
If I have a vector like below:

```
  a=[1 2 5 4 3 6]
```

At the end I need b like:

```
b=[1 1.5 2 3.5 5 4.5 4 3.5 3 4.5 6]
```

It can be done via loops but I try to do via matlab function is it possible to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "brute force way":

```
b = zeros( 1, 2*numel(a)-1 );
b(1:2:end) = a; % take care of the original values
b(2:2:end) = 0.5*( a(1:end-1) + a(2:end) ); % the mean
```

Using [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html):

```
b = interp1( 1:2:(2*numel(a)-1), a, 1:(2*numel(a)-1), 'linear' )
```